# Count column A if column B has the value "Closed" VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to count how many sites (the sites IDs are always unique) meet the status closed. The columns with the sites ids and the status are separated.

I can count the ones that meet the status just fine, but when I try to count the sites that meet the status I get 0 although I know it's not zero.

This is the excel file

[image: this is the excel file]

This is the code on the "With status" column

```
=COUNTIF('Rollout Plan'!AH:AH,"Closed")
```

this is what I'm trying to do on the "Sites QTY" column, a guy on the MrExcel forums suggested it

Code:

```
=COUNTIFS('Rollout Plan'!AH2:AH1000,"Closed",'Rollout Plan'!C:C,"<>"&"")
```

The C column on the Rollout plan is the one with the sites IDs

[image: c column]

The problem is, I'm getting a #VALUE! instead of a number and I don't know why.

Comment: @YowE3K I'm getting the same result. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two ranges within the COUNTIFS statement are not of the same size

```
=COUNTIFS('Rollout Plan'!AH2:AH1000,"Closed",'Rollout Plan'!C:C,"<>"&"")
```

One is a range that is 999 rows by 1 column, and the other is a really large number of rows by 1 column.

Try using

```
=COUNTIFS('Rollout Plan'!AH2:AH1000,"Closed",'Rollout Plan'!C2:C1000,"<>")
```

(As mentioned in a now-deleted comment, "<>"&"" is the same as "<>")